# How to set class attribute to @Html.TextBox() in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have tried something like this:

```
@Html.TextBox("txtFirstName", new { class="UserInputText"})
```

but it's showing that **class="UserInputText"** in textbox field as placeholder.

Comment: `@Html.TextBox("txtFirstName", null, new { @class="UserInputText"})` (the 2nd parameter is the value to display in the input. Then stop using this and use the strongly typed `TextBoxFor()` method so that you can bind to a model property.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Actually i have an issue with class attribute only which is solved hence i didn't checked for second parameter. Anyways your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use @class

```
@Html.TextBox("txtFirstName",  null,new { @class="UserInputText"})
```

Comment: The outputs `{ class = UserInputText }` in the textbox and does not add a `class` attribute (exactly what OP does not want)